# How to get icons to you the top of the main container

Tags: html, css

hey guys i am new to css in general , I am having a small problem with positioning a couple of social icons, basicaly , all i want to acheive is the following :

1. the social icons should be centered.
2. the social icons should touch the top of the main container div .

the 1st objective i have acheived , but i am having difficulty with the secound . , below is the HTML and CSS code :

HTML ::

```
    <section id="contact-us" class="contact-us">
                <div class="overlay">

                    <div class="social-icons">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href=""> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="">
                                    <i>|</i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href=""> 
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

        </div>
</section>
```

CSS ::

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

.contact-us {
    background: url(http://wallpaperswiki.com/wallpapers/2012/12/Abstract-Color-Point-1050x1400.jpg);
    height: 100%;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(146,39,143,.5);
}

.social-icons {
    text-align: center;
}

.social-icons ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.social-icons ul li {
    margin-left: 5px; 
    margin-right: 5px; 
    display: inline-block;
}

.social-icons li a {
    color: #fff;
}

.social-icons li a i {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/d1je8bs7/2/)**

notice how the social icons are not touching the top of the main container. actually , all three elements , the 2 social icons and the line inbetween them should touch the top of the main container.

**ON inspection** :: i am using bootstap , and bootstap has a line-height of 1.42857 as default , if i make the line-height on `social-icons` to `0` the socia icons get closer to the top , NEARLY SOLVES MY PROBLEM . but still not all three icons are touching the top ? WHY ? and how do i solve this problem ?

**EDIT** ::

The output i want is the following :
[image: the output i want]

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: The issue is the line-height of the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: Can you post the output screenshot you are trying?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/Ljba7Lgf/

Comment: or you can set their position to relative and then using CSS `top` property just change it according to your self and i tell you the value of the `top` property should be negative see here: http://jsfiddle.net/d1je8bs7/3/

Comment: @anni , that would be my last resort , but yeah surely an option, ty

Comment: @ManojKumar posted a screenshot

Comment: @Dmitriy yeah thats what i want , but somehow , `vertical-align` , makes all icons , not so proportionate to each others size , I.E. one icon looks as though its positioned right to the top

Comment: the other way is to decrease the size of `|` in between the social icon to 11px

Comment: Add a custom class to `|` and `position: relative;` `top: -10px`

Comment: @everyone thanks for your help guys ! i think i can find the solution not  , `vertical-align` does indeed solves my problem !

Comment: Great. Now update your code and share it with us.